# Simple video editor for youtube

Tags: video-editing

I am using Windows movie maker but it is now unsupported and lacks a couple of features I would like. What software would let me do the following

- take 1080i video from my Nikon camera (MOV H.264/MPEG-4 AVC with AAC sound)
- add a 10 second title with my text overlaid on a still from the video
- cut out sections of video
- mute some sections
- add overlaid subtitles for selected position and duration
- record new audio voiceover for sections
- generate & insert short video sections from stills
- output in a format suitable for upload to Youtube

I'm not interested in special effects. I don't want spinning 3d titles with firework sparkles and dancing unicorn overlays. I don't care if transition types are limited.

I don't want to pay a fixed monthly fee. Free is good but a low-cost cost perpetual licence might be ok.

I tried Avidemux but found it difficult to work out how to add the sort of titles I want and it seems to focus on video codec arcana a bit too much for my liking.

Platform Windows 10, maybe Ubuntu.

Comment: Except for "record new audio voiceover for sections", I'd say take a look at [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/). They have AppImages for Linux, so you can try without installing. But it's also available for Windows if you rather want to use it there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html#) with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed. It is a programmatic experience rather than interactive but works very well. *(You just need a player such as VLC that shows you the times within the movie so as to select the bits that you would like to operate on).*

MoviePy runs under [Python](https://www.python.org/) *which you will need to install first on Windows* and uses [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) *which it downloads and installs for you on first use* so can output a huge range of formats.

**All** of the above is:

- Free (Gratis)
- Open Source
- Cross Platform.